# How to get lookup list item using Selenium 2.0 with C#

Tags: c#, firefox, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Im trying to select an item from lookup list, its not like drop down list. If you write something that matches the contents of the lookup list, all the matching contents show up in the list and you cannot simply type in the text field even if you know the item from lookup list, you HAVE to click on the item from lookup list in order for it to populate in the text field. 
What Im doing is, Im writing the complete text of a valid field value in the field so that it is the only item that appears in the lookup list and then trying to search that list item so that it can be clicked, but whatever i try, the item isnt found. here is what I have tried already:
here is the html:

```html
<body>

  <div class="body-home"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script></script>
  <div id="cboxOverlay" style="display: none;"></div>
  <div id="colorbox" class="" style="display: none;"></div>
  <ul id="ui-id-1" class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="z-index: 1; display: none; top: 456.783px; left: 468.033px; width: 247px;">

    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
      <a id="ui-id-27" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">
        <span style="padding:10px;"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
```

The last  tag in above html is the one Im trying to get.

here is the xpath that i tried, ive tried the cssSelecter as well, nothing works.

```
IWebElement selectItem = driverX.FindElement(By.XPath("/ul[@id='ui-id-1']/li[1]/a"));
selectItem.Click();
```

Any help is highly appreciated.
Sophia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to type/select and item from lookup list, you should initially click the parent that contains the ul/li items. When you click the parent of it, the style associated with the ul/li (display: none) will be removed, so that you can interact with the ul/li.

From the HTML posted, we can observe that UL has a style with attributed display: none, this means we can't interact with it or with its children. If you post the complete HTML/the website url, may we can find the solution.

For example, check [this](https://roofandfloor.com/) website, which has similar kind of lookup list and below is the solution.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace TestSelenium
{
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    public ChromeDriver browser;

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        try
        {
            browser = new ChromeDriver();
            browser.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://roofandfloor.com/");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

            // Select City.
            IWebElement parentDiv = browser.FindElement(By.ClassName("city-dropdown-search"));
            parentDiv.Click();
            this.SelectItem("Bangalore");

            // Select Property.
            parentDiv = browser.FindElement(By.ClassName("property-type-checkboxes"));
            parentDiv.Click();
            this.SelectItem("Villa");

            // Select Bed room. Need to write separate code for this.
            parentDiv = browser.FindElement(By.ClassName("bedroom-select-container"));
            parentDiv.Click();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);

            IWebElement items = browser.FindElement(By.ClassName("search-bedrooms"));
            foreach (IWebElement item in items.FindElements(By.TagName("span")))
            {
                if (item.Text.Contains("1 BHK"))
                {
                    item.Click();
                    break;
                }
            } 

            // Select Max budget.
            parentDiv = browser.FindElement(By.Id("s2id_priceMax"));
            parentDiv.Click();
            this.SelectItem("5 Lakhs");

            // Select Build up area.
            parentDiv = browser.FindElement(By.Id("s2id_areaMin"));
            parentDiv.Click();
            this.SelectItem("600 Sq.ft.");

            // Select Possession.
            parentDiv = browser.FindElement(By.Id("s2id_possessionDate"));
            parentDiv.Click();
            this.SelectItem("Ready to Occupy");
        }
        catch
        { }
    }


    private void SelectItem(string itemText)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);

        IWebElement items = browser.FindElement(By.Id("select2-drop")); 
        foreach (IWebElement item in items.FindElements(By.TagName("li")))
        {
            if (item.Text.Contains(itemText))
            {
                item.Click();
                break;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

}

Try to observe the HTML of the posted portal. The above solution works fine to select the lookup items.

Comment: Thank you Sham for such detailed answer. it was very helpful. When I type in the text of an item and the possible matches load in the drop down list, a text appears in the html "xx results are available", xx being number of matches. and i used this if condition, if (item.Text.Contains("results are available")). Its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Sophia,

Maybe you should try the most literal test 1st, i.e. by a known `Id` to see that it works:

```
IWebElement selectItem = driverX.FindElement(By.Id("ui-id-27"));
selectItem.Click();
```

Once you've established this, then you can really look closely at the generic structure (obviously using `ui-id-27` is for this test only). I would then move onto looking at the XPath structure in the real case and establish a test between the presented Id and the generic Xpath element.